# Haskell, How to define mean by recursion, median and variance?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How to calculate the sample mean of a list of number by recursion. implement sample variance? implement sample median?

I have done this for just for sample mean I am struggling with sample mean by recursion, sample variance, and sample median? Thanks

```
mean :: [Float] -> Float

mean xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Comment: Could you tell what you've already tried?

Comment: well, as I mentioned I done this and don't know the mean by variance read a few text book but didnt really get.                                                                  mean :: [Float] -> Float

mean xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)

Comment: *"implement sample variance? implement sample median?"* This isn't a search engine, we don't speak Google haiku. Since English isn't your first language, add a proper question in your own language in the comments. With a little bit of luck, someone who speaks your language will translate it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `mean` recursively in several ways, but the way I'm going to suggest minimizes the number of divisions necessary for efficiency:

```
mean :: [Float] -> Float
mean [] = error "Can't take mean of empty list"
mean xs = go 0 0 xs
    where
        go len runningSum []     = runningSum / len
        go len runningSum (x:xs) = go (len + 1) (runningSum + x) xs
```

Note that while an experience Haskeller might write this code first, they would probably translate this with `foldl'` to remove the explicit recursion and benefit from strictness:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

mean [] = error "Can't take mean of empty list"
mean xs = uncurry (/) $ foldl' go (0, 0) xs
    where go (len, runningSum) x = (len + 1, runningSum + x)
```

This formulation even avoids the `fromIntegral` since `len` and `runningSum` can be inferred to be `Float` by the compiler.

For median, recursion is a really poor tool.  You'll be much better off implementing it with `Data.List.sort`, `length`, and `take`.  If you want recursion to be involved, implement quicksort or something.  If it's required for a class (this looks a lot like homework), then you'll have to figure it out yourself, SO is not a homework help website.